# Fullcalendar resource name missing in header

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I use the licensed fullcalendar with `groupByDateAndResource` set to true. I don't show a header as I built a custom one.

1. On the day view I only see the resource title but no date
2. On the other views I only see the date no resource title

How can I show both on both all views the way it appears in the documentation.

This is how my calendar object is configured (I use angular):

```
calendar: {
      defaultDate: this.$stateParams.date,
      height: $window.innerHeight - 45,
      editable: true,
      resources: [],
      groupByDateAndResource: true,
      header: '',
      defaultView: 'agendaWorkWeek',
      firstDay: 1,
      minTime: '07:00:00',
      maxTime: '22:00:00',
      axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      slotLabelInterval: '1:00',
      allDaySlot: false,
      eventColor: '#333333',
      eventTextColor: '#000',
      columnFormat: {
        month: 'dddd',
        agendaWeek: 'ddd, MMM D',
        agendaDay: 'dddd, MMM D, YYYY'
      },
      nowIndicator: true,
      displayEventTime: true,
      displayEventEnd: {
        month: false,
        basicWeek: true,
        'default': true
      },
      views: {
        agendaThreeDay: {
          type: 'agenda',
          columnFormat: 'ddd, MMM D',
          duration: {days: 3}
        },
        agendaWorkWeek: {
          type: 'agenda',
          columnFormat: 'ddd, MMM D',
          duration: {days: 7},
          weekends: false
        }
      },
      dayClick: dayClick,
      eventClick: eventClick,
      eventResize: changeTime,
      eventDrop: changeTime,
      windowResize: windowResize
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a css problem. Did you overwrite the height for `.fc-widget-header`? That would make sense if you had no resources but if you have them it will lead to your issues.